# How to generate user manual using Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard, doxygen-addtogroup

I had some user manual with .docx extension. can i convert  my manual similar to doxygen manual(with side navigation bar with headings)

Comment: Is the file with extension `.docx` plain ASCII or ? What do you want to do exactly as this is not clear, do you want to run doxygen on the `.doxcx` files or use another program to create a navigation side bar? What is your required output type: HTML, LaTeX, ...

Comment: @albert , actually i created user manual for my project (with .docx extension). it contain index pages followed by content with images. i need a html output by using doxygen.(similar to  https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html ).

Comment: Which program did you use to "i created user manual for my project (with .docx extension)"?

Comment: @albert, i created manually by using microsoft word.

Comment: I did suspect this already, doxygen cannot read Microsoft word documents, so you have to export this first to a format that doxygen does understand i.e. plain text with markdown commands (search for "convert Microsoft word to markdown" or have a look at pandoc for this job).

Comment: @albert , if i convert docx to markdown data will be same(i.e images, indexes etc)??

Comment: Well conversion between different markup versions can always be a bit different, due to the difference in the markup strategies of the formats, so one always has to carefully check the result of the conversion. Most likely images will be OK for other quantities I don't know, the only way is try it. (Microsoft word is a hard format due to the fact that it is a propriety format).